# Webservice Notification - what java implementation would you recommend?

Tags: java, .net, web-services, notifications

I'm looking to listen to WSN produced by a .net webservice using java. What java implementation for WSN would you  recommend in this case?

Comment: could you please rephrase your question, like what exactly you are looking for? Are you looking for something which receives web service response and process it?

Comment: My .net web services are sending notifications (http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/wsn/) which I need to capture and process in my java code. It is a sort of pub/sub mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Notification (or even Solicit response message exchange patterns) are **not** supported in Java web services.
Having said that it should be possible to implement a subscribe/publish mechanism by exposing a web service endpoints to "listen" for notifications and subscribe its url at the notification registry.
The endpoint will receive all the events/notifications from the notification service and then do the processing as needed.
To implement the web service you can use
- cxf
- axis
- jax ws
- spring ws  etc take your pick.